# Append Image to Data-href facebook share button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

Hi Everyone I am getting image in **imglink** variable

```
var imglink =$("<img>", {"src":  base64_string, "width": "250px", "height": "250px"}).appendTo("#img_preview");
```

Now I am trying to append data-href along with image in facebook share button like this

```
var anchor = $('.fb-share-button').attr('data-href', imglink);
```

**Result**

it's showing  
data-href="[object object]"

**Expected Result**

```
data-href="image_path"
```

facebook share button

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a></div>
```

js fiddle with whole code
  https://jsfiddle.net/fogeopjs/

please somebody help me out

Answer (score 0):

Your `imgLink` is a jQuery object, not a URL. Try getting its `src` attribute first, like so:

```
var anchor = $('.fb-share-button').attr('data-href', imglink.attr('src'))
```

### Demo:

```js
google.charts.load("current", {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Element', 'Density', {
      role: 'style'
    }],
    ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333', ],
    ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver'],
    ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
    ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2']
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
    bar: {
      groupWidth: '95%'
    },
    legend: 'none',
  };

  var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chart_div);

  // Wait for the chart to finish drawing before calling the getImageURI() method.
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
    chart_div1.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
    var imglink = chart.getImageURI();
    var base64_string = chart.getImageURI();

    // create image
    var imglink = $("<img>", {
      "src": base64_string,
      "width": "250px",
      "height": "250px"
    }).appendTo("#img_preview");
    var anchor = $('.fb-share-button').attr('data-href', imglink.attr('src'));

    console.log(anchor.data('href'));

  });
  chart.draw(data, options);


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id='chart_div'></div>
<div id='chart_div1'></div>
<div id="img_preview" style="width:250px; height:250px;"></div>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a></div>
```

Comment: Hi i have tried now in data-href it's returning a big string instead of image and I have opened that string in new tab. I can see the image is coming correctly but when I am trying to share on fb image is not going

Comment: You can't share a base64 image on Facebook, most likely. You'll have to host it on a server or at some other URL to use it.

Comment: My problem is I am dynamically generating google chart after that I want to share that chart on facebook, here is my server url  http://vps4.techiva.com/projects/chart.php  can you please give some step by step instruction so I can proceed. I am new to it really sorry.

Comment: I can't help you with uploading files automatically to your server, sorry; that would be a better candidate for another question.